# What is an Eclipse Spring STS "Config Set" good for?

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, config, javabeans

I have the Spring STS plugin activated within my Eclipse project.  Doing this enabled many cool Spring features including specialized management of Spring bean files.  However, I noticed that the project settings for Spring allows for the creation of "Config Sets" -- which look like groups of bean configuration files.

I cannot find documentation for this feature anywhere...anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use "config sets" to display the dependencies between Spring beans in several different context files.

Comment: I see -- if you create a set, then the set shows up in the project explorer under "Spring Elements" -> "Beans".  If you click right on the config set name you can display the dependencies in a graph at once.   Kinda cool I guess...but very non-obvious!  Thanks!

Comment: I agree. It's not obvious. But it's quite nice to show dependencies between **XML** configured beans.